# Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "DialogResult" и "bool"

Tags: c#

```
private string pathFile;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void CoderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Всё файлы (*.*) |*.*| Файлы Shirase (*.shirase)|*.shirase";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        pathFile = openFileDialog.FileName;
        OpenFile.Text = pathFile.ToString();

        DisplayFile(pathFile);
    }
}
```

Оператор `==` невозможно применить к операнду типа `DialogResult` и `bool`
Как мне пофиксить?
Такой же код, но на C# WPF работает, а на Windows Form ошибка.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117284/discussion-on-question-by-bohdan------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `WPF`, метод [`Window.ShowDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=net-5.0) возвращает `bool?`

В `WinForms`, метод [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=net-5.0) возвращает [`DialogResult`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult?view=net-5.0)

Так как методы вызываются у разных классов и имеют разные типы возвращаемых значений - просто так перенести код может не получиться.

В данном случае достаточно заменить сравнение результата с `true`, на сравнение с нужным значением `enum`, например

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```